After installing latest updates on Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS (kernel 5.15.0-110) the amdgpu driver crashes at boot
Running Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS on an Acer Aspire 5 laptop. Yesterday several updates were installed including Linux kernel 5.15.0.110. When I rebooted after the install the system wouldn't boot, or a least, I didn't get the usual login screen. Rebooted and used "advanced boot" options to select the previous kernel and was successful.
Looked at logs and found this in dmesg : (sorry for the length)
[    2.843409] kernel: amdgpu: HMM registered 2048MB device memory
[    2.843514] kernel: amdgpu: Topology: Add APU node [0x15d8:0x1002]
[    2.843523] kernel: kfd kfd: amdgpu: added device 1002:15d8
[    2.843542] kernel: kfd kfd: amdgpu: Failed to resume IOMMU for device 1002:15d8
[    2.843565] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: amdgpu_device_ip_init failed
[    2.843583] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: Fatal error during GPU init
[    2.843600] kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: amdgpu: finishing device.
[    2.857878] kernel: [drm:dal_irq_service_dummy_ack [amdgpu]] *ERROR* dal_irq_service_dummy_ack: called for non-implemented irq source
[    2.858514] kernel: [drm:dal_irq_service_dummy_set [amdgpu]] *ERROR* dal_irq_service_dummy_set: called for non-implemented irq source
[    2.859157] kernel: BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 000000000000013c
[    2.859171] kernel: #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
[    2.859184] kernel: #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
[    2.859196] kernel: PGD 0 P4D 0 
[    2.859210] kernel: Oops: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP NOPTI
[    2.859223] kernel: CPU: 4 PID: 225 Comm: systemd-udevd Not tainted 5.15.0-110-lowlatency #120-Ubuntu
[    2.859244] kernel: Hardware name: Acer Aspire A515-43/Grumpy_PK, BIOS V1.12 08/20/2021
[    2.859258] kernel: RIP: 0010:amdgpu_dm_fini+0x149/0x1f0 [amdgpu]
[    2.859764] kernel: Code: 01 00 48 85 ff 74 10 e8 a5 0f 27 00 48 c7 83 e0 4e 01 00 00 00 00 00 4c 8b 83 48 4f 01 00 4d 85 c0 74 66 48 8b 93 40 3e 01 00 <8b> 82 3c 01 00 00 85 c0 74 42 45 31 e4 49 63 c4 4c 8d 2c 40 4b 8b
[    2.859793] kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffaedfc0cab948 EFLAGS: 00010282
[    2.859808] kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff888fdd500000 RCX: 0000000000c72004
[    2.859822] kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: fcc080a4c203401f RDI: 0000000000037060
[    2.859838] kernel: RBP: ffffaedfc0cab960 R08: ffff888fde739d40 R09: 0000000000000000
[    2.859853] kernel: R10: ffff888fdd45b150 R11: dead000000000122 R12: ffff888fdd500000
[    2.859867] kernel: R13: ffff888fdd500070 R14: 0000000000000007 R15: 0000000000000001
[    2.859883] kernel: FS:  00007f4f324e38c0(0000) GS:ffff889478b00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[    2.859901] kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[    2.859914] kernel: CR2: 000000000000013c CR3: 000000011a7a4000 CR4: 00000000003506e0
[    2.859929] kernel: Call Trace:
[    2.859940] kernel:  <TASK>
[    2.859949] kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[    2.859966] kernel:  ? show_trace_log_lvl+0x28e/0x2ea
[    2.859984] kernel:  ? show_trace_log_lvl+0x28e/0x2ea
[    2.860009] kernel:  ? dm_hw_fini+0x23/0x30 [amdgpu]
[    2.860512] kernel:  ? show_regs.part.0+0x23/0x29
[    2.860527] kernel:  ? __die_body.cold+0x8/0xd
[    2.860544] kernel:  ? __die+0x2b/0x37
[    2.860559] kernel:  ? page_fault_oops+0x13b/0x170
[    2.860583] kernel:  ? do_user_addr_fault+0x33e/0x690
[    2.860598] kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[    2.860614] kernel:  ? exc_page_fault+0x77/0x190
[    2.860634] kernel:  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x27/0x30
[    2.860657] kernel:  ? amdgpu_dm_fini+0x149/0x1f0 [amdgpu]
[    2.861155] kernel:  ? amdgpu_dm_fini+0x12b/0x1f0 [amdgpu]
[    2.861650] kernel:  dm_hw_fini+0x23/0x30 [amdgpu]
[    2.862143] kernel:  amdgpu_device_ip_fini_early.isra.0+0x278/0x312 [amdgpu]
[    2.862655] kernel:  amdgpu_device_fini_hw+0x156/0x208 [amdgpu]
[    2.863160] kernel:  amdgpu_driver_unload_kms+0x69/0x90 [amdgpu]
[    2.863548] kernel:  amdgpu_driver_load_kms.cold+0x81/0x107 [amdgpu]
[    2.864053] kernel:  amdgpu_pci_probe+0x1d1/0x290 [amdgpu]
[    2.864438] kernel:  local_pci_probe+0x4b/0x90
[    2.864456] kernel:  ? pci_match_device+0xe2/0x140
[    2.864472] kernel:  pci_device_probe+0x119/0x200
[    2.864490] kernel:  really_probe+0x222/0x420
[    2.864508] kernel:  __driver_probe_device+0xe8/0x140
[    2.864524] kernel:  driver_probe_device+0x23/0xc0
[    2.864539] kernel:  __driver_attach+0xf7/0x1f0
[    2.864554] kernel:  ? __device_attach_driver+0x140/0x140
[    2.864569] kernel:  bus_for_each_dev+0x7f/0xd0
[    2.864585] kernel:  driver_attach+0x1e/0x30
[    2.864598] kernel:  bus_add_driver+0x148/0x220
[    2.864611] kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[    2.864627] kernel:  driver_register+0x95/0x100
[    2.864642] kernel:  __pci_register_driver+0x68/0x70
[    2.864658] kernel:  amdgpu_init+0x7c/0x1000 [amdgpu]
[    2.865005] kernel:  ? 0xffffffffc1106000
[    2.865018] kernel:  do_one_initcall+0x49/0x210
[    2.865037] kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[    2.865050] kernel:  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x1a6/0x320
[    2.865072] kernel:  do_init_module+0x52/0x260
[    2.865090] kernel:  load_module+0xb46/0xc30
[    2.865111] kernel:  __do_sys_finit_module+0xbf/0x120
[    2.865137] kernel:  __x64_sys_finit_module+0x18/0x20
[    2.865151] kernel:  x64_sys_call+0x1ac3/0x1fa0
[    2.865166] kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x56/0xb0
[    2.865179] kernel:  ? x64_sys_call+0x3b9/0x1fa0
[    2.865193] kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[    2.865206] kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x63/0xb0
[    2.865219] kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[    2.865231] kernel:  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x35/0x50
[    2.865245] kernel:  ? x64_sys_call+0x1e12/0x1fa0
[    2.865259] kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[    2.865271] kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x63/0xb0
[    2.865284] kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[    2.865296] kernel:  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x35/0x50
[    2.865310] kernel:  ? x64_sys_call+0x1a81/0x1fa0
[    2.865324] kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[    2.865336] kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x63/0xb0
[    2.865351] kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x67/0xd1
[    2.865366] kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f4f32bdd88d
[    2.865379] kernel: Code: 5b 41 5c c3 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 73 b5 0f 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
[    2.865409] kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffd6ffe9e68 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
[    2.865428] kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055b2c3ee70b0 RCX: 00007f4f32bdd88d
[    2.865443] kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007f4f32d75441 RDI: 0000000000000018
[    2.865457] kernel: RBP: 0000000000020000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000002
[    2.865471] kernel: R10: 0000000000000018 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007f4f32d75441
[    2.865486] kernel: R13: 000055b2c3eaac30 R14: 000055b2c3eb8c90 R15: 000055b2c3eb2450
[    2.865510] kernel:  </TASK>
[    2.865518] kernel: Modules linked in: usbhid amdgpu(+) iommu_v2 gpu_sched i2c_algo_bit drm_ttm_helper ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt crct10dif_pclmul fb_sys_fops crc32_pclmul hid_generic cec ghash_clmulni_intel rc_core ahci sha256_ssse3 sha1_ssse3 aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd psmouse libahci i2c_hid_acpi nvme drm r8169 i2c_hid xhci_pci nvme_core realtek i2c_piix4 xhci_pci_renesas video wmi hid
[    2.865673] kernel: CR2: 000000000000013c
[    2.865685] kernel: ---[ end trace 6ed2448758778b07 ]---
[    2.865696] kernel: RIP: 0010:amdgpu_dm_fini+0x149/0x1f0 [amdgpu]
[    2.866198] kernel: Code: 01 00 48 85 ff 74 10 e8 a5 0f 27 00 48 c7 83 e0 4e 01 00 00 00 00 00 4c 8b 83 48 4f 01 00 4d 85 c0 74 66 48 8b 93 40 3e 01 00 <8b> 82 3c 01 00 00 85 c0 74 42 45 31 e4 49 63 c4 4c 8d 2c 40 4b 8b
[    2.866227] kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffaedfc0cab948 EFLAGS: 00010282
[    2.866242] kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff888fdd500000 RCX: 0000000000c72004
[    2.866256] kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: fcc080a4c203401f RDI: 0000000000037060
[    2.866270] kernel: RBP: ffffaedfc0cab960 R08: ffff888fde739d40 R09: 0000000000000000
[    2.866284] kernel: R10: ffff888fdd45b150 R11: dead000000000122 R12: ffff888fdd500000
[    2.866298] kernel: R13: ffff888fdd500070 R14: 0000000000000007 R15: 0000000000000001
[    2.866313] kernel: FS:  00007f4f324e38c0(0000) GS:ffff889478b00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[    2.866330] kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[    2.866344] kernel: CR2: 000000000000013c CR3: 000000011a7a4000 CR4: 00000000003506e0

So I guess the system was running but with a crashed "amdgpu" display/gpu driver.
Managed to figure out how to use Muon to remove the linux-image-5-15-0-110-lowlatency
and linux-modules-5-15-9-110-lowlatency packages and lock the appropriate '107' versions (old kernel release) so they wouldn't get upgraded.
So now what? Wait a week and see what comes down the update pike? I would like to report this behavior someplace... unless it already got reported via "whoopsie".
Dave (RBdigital)
edit to reflect correct names of removed packages

I had a similar issue as well. I booted to an older kernel, then updated to 6.5.0 and it is working without any problems. Using an older kernel until they fix it can also work.

Thanks! I might just stay here until I can upgrade to the 24.04LTS (in August sometime) which has kernel 6.8.....
